# How to set value of input text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an input text which is this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "Employee Number")
</div>

<div class="editor-field textBoxEmployeeNumber">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
</div>
```

Which produce following html

```html
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="EmployeeId">Employee Number</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field textBoxEmployeeNumber">
  <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EmployeeId must be a number." data-val-required="The EmployeeId field is required." id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" type="text" value="" />

  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmployeeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I want to set the value of this input text using jquery so i did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.textBoxEmployeeNumber').val("fgg");
    });
</script>
```

however, it is not working... what is the error in my syntax?

Comment: i used the input text inside a form....

Answer (score 561, accepted):

Your selector is retrieving the text box's surrounding `<div class='textBoxEmployeeNumber'>` instead of the input inside it.

```
// Access the input inside the div with this selector:
$(function () {
  $('.textBoxEmployeeNumber input').val("fgg");
});
```

#### Update after seeing output HTML

If the ASP.NET code reliably outputs the HTML `<input>` with an id attribute `id='EmployeeId'`, you can more simply just use:

```
$(function () {
  $('#EmployeeId').val("fgg");
});
```

Failing this, you will need to verify in your browser's error console that you don't have other script errors causing this to fail.  The first example above [works correctly in this demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/a2fDQ/)

Comment: tried that, not working.... tried also .textBoxEmployeeNumber input=[type="text"]... not working also

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Reservation</legend>
            .........
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "Employee Number")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field textBoxEmployeeNumber">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            </div>..........

Comment: <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="EmployeeId">Employee Number</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field textBoxEmployeeNumber">

                <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EmployeeId must be a number." data-val-required="The EmployeeId field is required." id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmployeeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

            </div>

Comment: @RojBeraña Does the browser read code inside your $(document).ready function? place alert there: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> alert('entered');
        $(function () {$('#EmployeeId').val("fgg"); }); 
        </script>

Comment: Have similar problem, value is visible in browser, but when I check code with F12, there is `value=""` and empty filed in DB after saving.

Comment: .val doesn't work for me. The text doesn't appear in the input box

Answer (score 76):

Using jQuery, we can use the following code:

Select by input name:

```
$('input[name="textboxname"]').val('some value')
```

Select by input class:

```
$('input[type=text].textboxclass').val('some value')
```

Select by input id:

```
$('#textboxid').val('some value')
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#EmployeeId').val("fgg");

    //Or
    $('.textBoxEmployeeNumber > input').val("fgg");

    //Or
    $('.textBoxEmployeeNumber').find('input').val("fgg");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For element with id

```
<input id="id_input_text16" type="text" placeholder="Ender Data"></input>
```

You can set the value as

```
$("#id_input_text16").val("testValue");
```

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 4):

this is for classes

```
$('.nameofdiv').val('we are developers');
```

for ids

```
$('#nameofdiv').val('we are developers');
```

now if u have an iput in a form u can use

```
$("#form li.name input.name_val").val('we are awsome developers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation for a file upload that has a nicer looking bootstrap button than the default file upload browse button.  This is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2  control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-1 btn btn-sn btn-primary" id="browseButton" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">browse</div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input id="fileSpace" name="uploaded_file"  type="file" style="display: none;">   @*style="display: none;"*@
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "modelField"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
        $('#fileSpace').on("change", function () {
        $("#modelField").val($('input[name="uploaded_file"]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure js it will be simpler

```
EmployeeId.value = 'fgg';
```

```js
EmployeeId.value = 'fgg';
```

```html
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="EmployeeId">Employee Number</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field textBoxEmployeeNumber">
  <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EmployeeId must be a number." data-val-required="The EmployeeId field is required." id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" type="text" value="" />
  
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmployeeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```