# jQuery not changing value for input text with plus/minus button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple plus and minus button next to my input. This works fine. However, it's not actually changing the value once the number is set in the form. This is causing problems since I have a calculator that changes based on the value of my input. Is there a way to make jQuery change the actual value when the plus/minus buttons are used? I can manually type a number and it works fine.

I have tried using `.change()` and `.attr('value' currentVal)` with no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v1pje44v/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value of input text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery)

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for 0-10 numbers. Is that what you expected? Or what is `actual` value?

Comment: Yes. That part is working fine. However, it's not actually changing the value. It's still equal to 0. My calculator is checking the value of the input to determine what value to actually calculate.

Comment: The actual html input value is not changing there fore his calc is always getting 0 fyi

Comment: So is there no way for jQuery to change that?

Comment: Click button in this fiddle - it updates alright: http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/j1asaxcy/

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If you see it changed...it's value is changed. Note that the attribute will always be the same, only the value property will change

Comment: Probably something wrong with how you try to get the input value. The `$('#yourInputId').val()` from my fiddle above works fine.

Comment: only have to do `$(".qty").val(currentVal - 1)` for set values.

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v1pje44v/ . Here in console. your `attribute` `value` is always `0` and `property` `value` is changing. You have to check `attr` and `prop` differance.

Comment: I am trying to change the attribute value.

Comment: then you should set `attr('value', 50);` Can it make sense? what is going wrong?

Comment: I tried doing that but still gave me an error.

Comment: If I do this `$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').attr('value', currentVal + 1);` it will not increment on click.

Comment: yes for that you need to use `.val()` its a property of input. Don't mix `attr` and `prop`

Comment: So would i set `attr()` in the variable?

Comment: No. Only use `.val()` for `property`.

Comment: That's how I currently have it. So what it does is on load it has the value set to 0 as defined in the input. If I change it directly in the textbox it works as normal. however, if I use plus/minus and then click back into the box it will change back to 0. So I need to change what the plus/minus are changing I just don't know how.

Comment: The link you shared is working fine.. It is changing with + and - Sign.

Comment: yes, but it is not changing the value of the input. Which is what I need it to do for my calculator reading the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

Change

```
var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val();
$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(10);
$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
```

To

```
var currentVal = parseInt($('.qty').val());
$('.qty').val(currentVal + 1);
$('.qty').val(10);
$('.qty').val(currentVal - 1);
$('.qty').val(0);
```

This respective change will work for you.

Comment: I tried `$('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    trigger('keyup');` with no luck.

Comment: Oh sorry! OK that sort of worked. For it to pick it up I have to click back into the box. However, I am not sure if this is the best approach. Since users will be clicking plus or minus they are going to want to see the calculator change as soon as they do so.

Comment: @ Lynx I changed my code.I wish it will work for you

Comment: Sorry. I still get the same issue.