# Get the values of two input elements and check the value ot third. Set value to forth element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input elements and one select element. What I want is to get the values of the input elements and check the value of the select. the input elements are product base price and price-mark up so they are decimal numbers.

The select is with values 1 and 2. 1 is Fixed price and 2 is Percentage.

So, I want to check if the base price input field has a value and the price mark field has a value and check the select field.

If the input fields are not blank and the select = 1 ( fixed price ),
then sum the base price and the price mark fields and set the result as a value of the 4th field, which is "price".

If the select value is = 2 (percentage) then get the base price and + or - the number in price mark ( considered as percentage).

So far I have the below code:

```
<div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-base_price"><?php echo $entry_base_price; ?></label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">

              <input type="text" name="base_price" value="<?php echo $base_price; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_base_price; ?>" id="base_price" class="form-control" />

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-price_mark"><?php echo $entry_price_mark; ?></label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">

              <input type="text" name="price_mark" value="<?php echo $price_mark; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price_mark; ?>" id="price_mark" class="form-control" />

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-price_mark_type"><?php echo $entry_price_mark_type; ?></label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">

              <select name="price_mark_type" id="price_mark_type" class="form-control">
                <option value="1"><?php echo $entry_fixed_price;?></option>
                <option value="2"><?php echo $entry_percent;?></option>
              </select>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-price"><?php echo $entry_price; ?></label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <script type="text/javascript">

            base_price = $("#base_price").attr('value');
            price_mark = $("#price_mark").attr('value');
            price_mark_type = $("#price_mark_type").attr('value');

            fixed = base_price + price_mark;
            percent = base_price * (price_mark / 100);

              if (base_price && price_mark == 1 ) {
                  $('#price').val(fixed);
              }
              if (base_price && price_mark == 2 ) {
                  $('#price').val(percent);
              }

            </script>
              <input type="text" value="" name="price" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" id="price" class="form-control" />

            </div>

          </div>
```

I also tried and :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

              var base_price = document.getElementById("base_price").value;
              var price_mark = document.getElementById("price_mark").value;

              var price_mark_type = document.getElementById("price_mark_type").value;



              if (base_price && price_mark == 1 ) {
                  document.getElementById("price").value = 'parceInt(base_price) + parceInt(price_mark)';
              }
              if (base_price && price_mark == 2 ) {
                  document.getElementById("price").value = 'parceInt(base_price) * (parceInt(price_mark) / 100)';
              }

            </script>
```

I tried these suggestions but no result so far:
[How to set value of input text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery)

[Get the value in an input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery,
price_mark_type = $("#price_mark_type").val() should return 1 or 2.

base_price && price_mark == 1 should be instead base_price && price_mark_type == 1

```
var base_price = $("#base_price").val();
            var price_mark = $("#price_mark").val();
            var price_mark_type = $("#price_mark_type").val();

            if (base_price && price_mark_type == 1) {
                $("#price").val(parseInt(base_price) + parseInt(price_mark));
            }
            else if (base_price && price_mark_type == 2) {
                $("#price").val(parseInt(base_price) + (parseInt(base_price) * (parseInt(price_mark) / 100)));
            }
```

Comment: but the price_mark_type defines if the price_mark is fixed price or if it is percentage. The price_mark field can be 15,33 ot whatever number.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you've two scenarios.
1. You want to check if base_price have value and price_mark_type =1 then calculate base_price + price_mark
2. You want to check if price_mark have value and price_mark_type=2 then calculate base_price * price_mark / 100; 
Yes?

Comment: yes. I have a base price for a product and I want to change it by fixed price or by persent.
Example: 
base_price = 100
price_mark = 20
If price_mark _type = 1 ( 1 is fixed price ), then it should make the " #price " input field 120.

Scenario #2:
Example: 
base_price = 85
price_mark = 10
If price_mark _type = 2 ( 2 is persentage ), then it should make the " #price " input field 93,5 ( add 10% on the base price).

Comment: I just tried it and it did not work. I also tried:

var base_price = $("#base_price").val();
                var price_mark = $("#price_mark").val();
                var price_mark_type = $("#price_mark_type").val();
                if (base_price && price_mark_type == 1) {
                  $("#price").value = parseFloat(base_price).toFixed(4) + parseInt(price_mark);
                 }
                  else if (base_price && price_mark_type == 2) {
                  $("#price").value = parseFloat(base_price).toFixed(4) * (parseInt(price_mark) / 100);
                 }

and nothing... :/

Comment: Look at the answer now. Also, if you want to update price upon selecting price_mark_type, you have to attach event listener. The current script do it on page load only.

Comment: If that worked for you, consider marking it as answer and +1

Answer (score 0):

Worked with:

```
 $('#price_mark').click(function(){
            var base_price = $("#base_price").val();
            var price_mark = $("#price_mark").val();
            var price_mark_type = $("#price_mark_type").val();

            if (base_price && price_mark_type == 1) {
                $("#price").val(parseInt(base_price) + parseInt(price_mark));
            }
            else if (base_price && price_mark_type == 2) {
                $("#price").val(parseInt(base_price) + (parseInt(base_price) * (parseInt(price_mark) / 100)));
            }
            });
```

Thanks to jeetaz!