# How to get value of jquery variable into textbox field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#university_name" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomplete.php',
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    var x = ui.item.value;
    }
    });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id = "university_name"  name = "university_name" value= "x" placeholder = "University Name" >
```

Here I want to place jquery variable value i.e var x  into input field value So How can we do this ?

Thank You

Comment: Simply `$("#university_name").val( your_var );`

Comment: `$("#university_name").val(  ui.item.value);` enough for u.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value of input text using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery)

Comment: `autocomplete` is getting invoked on same university_name field; then why you want to send its value explicitly? It will get set automatically whenever you select the value from search results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply hikmat sir But I have one more query sir if I want to use this value in a mysql query  is it possible or not if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using jquery `val()`

```
$('#university_name').val(x);
```

your full code will go like this

```
$( "#university_name" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomplete.php',
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    var x = ui.item.value;
    $('#university_name').val(x);
    }
    });
```

Comment: ya we can. just want to give quick update to the answer

Comment: `$('university_name').val(x);` will never going to work. Please update the answer.