# Change html select tag value dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have one select tag

I want to change select tag value `from value="-1:Select;" to value="-1:Select;2:option1"`

```
<select role="select" value="-1:Select;" id="brandingName" name="brandingName" size="1" class="FormElement">
</select>
```

> value="-1:Select;"

I have tried with below syntax but it does not change:

```
document.getElementById("brandingName").value = "-1:Select;2:option1";
```

How can I change this value using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Where is your try?

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle to recreating this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery

Comment: There is no `value` attribute on [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) elements

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the `id` and use `attr` to change `value`, like this with out having testing it.

```
$("#brandingName").attr("value", "-1:Select;2:option1")
```

Comment: `$(("#brandingName").val()` ???

Comment: I have tried with also but its not working $(("#brandingName").val()