# Set values in more input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

How can I set values (default values) in more input fields by JavaScript or jQuery? Thank you.

```
<form method="" action="">
Name: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php $value; ?>" placeholder="Your name"> <br><br>
Surname: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php $value; ?>" placeholder="Your surname"> <br><br>
Email: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php $value; ?>" placeholder="Your email"> <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value of input text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the values for input fields in jQuery you can use the `.val()` method:

```
$('#id1').val("This is a value");// the selector #id1 selects all elements with id "id1"
```

If you want to set multiple inputs to same value you need to use another selector as id's are designed to be unique:

```
$('.text-input').val("Some other value"); // this will set value of all elements with class text-input
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all inputs, and then set the default value with `element.value` syntaxis.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")).forEach(input => {
  input.value = "Default value has been assigned";
});
```

```html
Input 1: <input type="text">
Input 2: <input type="text">
Input 3: <input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `echo` the values.
Below is updated code.

```
<form method="" action="">
Name: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" placeholder="Your name"> <br><br>
Surname: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" placeholder="Your surname"> <br><br>
Email: <input type="text" id="id1" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" placeholder="Your email"> <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: I think he need a javascript or jquery method to set default

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to come up with a selector that selects all the elements that you would like to change.

Because you would like to change all the values of the text boxes, the following selector would do: `$("input['type=text']")`. And to change or set their value: just to: `$("input['type=text']").val('value');`

See a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/2od89uou/1/